# The type of message that scares people and forces them to forward it to others

Tags: word-request

I'm looking for the name of the type of message or comment that has scary content normally about bad luck. It will ask us to pass it to others, otherwise something bad will come to us.

Comment: Before the Internet, they used to be called _chain letters_.

Comment: There are now 'chain emails'.

Comment: Although we should specify that not all chain letters are about bad luck or threats.  Sometimes they specify that good luck or money will come to you if you pass on the message.

Comment: There's perhaps some precedent these days to call it a 'viral email' - in the same vein as a viral youtube video, as opposed to malware that is bad for your computer - but I wouldn't expect that to be in any dictionary yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such communications were once commonly called "chain letters", as the comment by  
Kate Bunting points out. That term is sometimes still used, even for emails. Th term "chain emails" is sometimes used.  If the communication solicits money, it may be called a "scam". If sent widewly, it may be called "spam". thoase last two terms are very general, however.

Note that not all chair letters or chain emails include scary threats **or** promises of benefits. Some merely invite the recipient to share a communication with throe who might be interested. Jokes and prayers often circulate in that way. So the term "chain letter" does not **specifically** imply such a threat or lure. I don't know of any specific term for just those emails with such threats or warnings.